# Why or how can we say errors(residuals) are independent and they follow the normal probabilties in regression analysis?

Tags: statistics, regression, statistical-inference, regression-analysis

While I am studying linear regression analysis and I have encountered a sentence salying "errors are independent and follow normal probabilities". I can only guess what it says but I can't trust my guess about it.

Can you guys please let me know what it means?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that "error" is not exactly synonymous with "residual".  If errors are independent, residuals are often negatively correlated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

It means that the errors (presumably in different measurements) are [independent random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#For_random_variables) with [jointly normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution).